# Reflexive closure proof (Pierce, ex. 2.2.6)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Simple exercise taken from the book Types and Programming Languages by Benjamin C. Pierce.

Suppose we are given a relation **R** on a set **S**. Define the relation **R'** as follows:

$$ R' = R \cup \{(s,s) | s \in S\} $$

That is, **R'** contains all the pairs in **R** plus all pairs of the form (s,s). Show that **R'** is the reflexive closure of R.

Questions:

1. Actually the proof.
2. Will it be a reflexive closure if $dom(R) \subset S$, I mean that it may happen that **R'** is not *smallest*

Definition:

Reflexive closure of R is the smalles reflexive relation R' that contains R.

Comment: 1. [ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Reflexive_Closure_Definitions). 2. A closer look at the definition of reflexive relation may be helpful. Also, before asking further questions, it may be advisable to think some more about these exercises yourself.

Comment: Thinking before you ask is good general advice but I think this question is better than most of the copy-paste majority in that regard.

Comment: @Lord_Farin 1. Thanks again for the link. 2. As you could guess, that's not the field I feel very comfortable, thus sorry for asking simple questions, but that's the only way I can proceed:)

Comment: @Ben I agree; it's not that I wanted to imply the questions are of poor quality. I just wanted to advise to go through them again, more thoroughly, and perhaps try to extract the general trains of thought present from the various proofs given. While there is quite the learning curve in starting mathematical proofs, it's only thorough and repeated exercise that will bring about the fruits and the insight. While tempting, going too fast through the easy parts may set you back later, not having thoroughly internalised all of the building blocks yet. (Mostly drawing from my own experience here...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for $R'$ to be reflexive on $S$, must contain every ordered pair $\langle s,s\rangle$ with $s\in S$. And those are the only ordered pairs that it has to contain, so adding any of them that aren't already there is enough to make the relation reflexive. That really is the proof right there.

Comment: Ok, so I was wrong that domain of reflexive relation on set S can be different from S. Just to check on my example: if $$ S = \{1,2,3,4,5\}, R = \{(1,2), (3,4)\}$$ then $$R' = \{(1,2), (3,4), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5)\}$$ am I right?

Comment: @Maxym: Yes that's perfectly correct. The definition of reflexivity subsumes the presence of an "underlying" or "carrying set" $S$.

Answer (score 1):

It is the smallest.

**Proof:** Let $H$ be a reflexive relation *on $S$* that extends $R$. being reflexive (*on $S$*) means that $(s,s)\in H$ for all $s\in S$. This shows that $R'\subseteq H$. Now we're left to check whether $R'$ is a reflexive extension of $R$ or not. And it is.